# Update in SQL PHP won't update

Tags: php

So i have this php project and the problem is this code;

```
try{
    $pdo->beginTransaction();


    $sql = "UPDATE lib_storeroom SET medicine_id=:med_id WHERE medicine_count = :medicine_count_prev + :medicine_qty";
    $s = $pdo -> prepare($sql);
    $s -> bindValue(':med_id', $_SESSION['med_id_pull']);
    $s -> bindValue(':medicine_count_prev', $_SESSION['med_qty']);
    $s -> bindValue(':medicine_qty', $_SESSION['replenish_qnty']);

    $s -> execute();

    $pdo->commit();
}
```

..and this doesn't update the value. Pls help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you've switched your `SET` and `WHERE` clauses.

Use this instead:

```
  $sql = "UPDATE lib_storeroom SET medicine_count = :medicine_count_prev + :medicine_qty WHERE medicine_id=:med_id";
```

Comment: still not working...still having the old value not the sum

Comment: oops...it works now...i dont know why but when i tried this code plus set my form in GET instead of POST, the value updated...thank you so much ^^